# Headless environment error in java.awt.Robot class with MAC OS

Tags: java, macos, javafx-2, headless, awtrobot

I am trying to capture screen shots in my JavaFX application using `Robot` class,

this is the code which I used in my application:

```
Rectangle screenBounds = new Rectangle(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth(),
           Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight());

Robot robot = new Robot();

BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new java.awt.Rectangle(
     (int) screenBounds.getX(), (int) screenBounds.getY(), (int) 
             screenBounds.getWidth(), (int) screenBounds.getHeight()));
```

It is working perfectly in *windows operating system*, but showing an error of `headless environment` in *MAC OS* at `Robot robot = new Robot();`

Comment: Can you post the error or exception

Comment: java.awt.AWTException: headless environment

at Robot robot = new Robot();

Comment: What Java Version is the Mac running?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is to answer my own question, after searching many resources.

I have used following code to disable headless environment, and the problem is solved.

```
static {

        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: did this work in headless environment ?

Answer (score 3):

From their API I can see the following:

1. The constructors of Applet and all heavyweight components (*) are
   changed to throw *HeadlessException* if a display, keyboard, and mouse
   are not supported by the toolkit implementation
2. The Robot constructor throws an *AWTException* if a display, keyboard,
   and mouse are not supported by the toolkit implementation
3. Many of the methods in Toolkit and GraphicsEnvironment, with the
   exception of fonts, imaging, and printing, are changed to throw
   *HeadlessException* if a display, keyboard, and mouse are not
   supported
4. Other methods that may be affected by lack of display, keyboard, or
   mouse support, are changed to throw *HeadlessException*
5. It should be worth noting that the *HeadlessException* is thrown if
   and only if isHeadless returns true, and that all javadoc comments
   should specify this

So you need to check your hardware and their drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this line of code `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");` before the `Robot robot = new Robot();`.