# JavaFx in headless mode

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to run JavaFx in headless mode(in Java 7)? It is being used to generate images on the server but is asking for an X-Server. Does there exist something like java.awt.headless in JavaFx ?(I can't use Xvfb )

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this problem for server-side image geneartion on Ubuntu linux environment with jetty application server. It uses xvfb but only as a "library" - without any additional special actions on server:

```
apt-get install xvfb

// then on application server start:

export DISPLAY=":99"

start-stop-daemon --start --background --user jetty --exec "/usr/bin/sudo" -- -u jetty /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24
```

You can see the details of my server-side image generation solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940329/javafx-for-server-side-image-generation).

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of problem which I encountered while capturing images in Mac OS.

I have solved this issue by using

```
static {

        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
}
```

See for reference : [Headless environment error in java.awt.Robot class with MAC OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487025/headless-environment-error-in-java-awt-robot-class-with-mac-os)

Comment: This is only for Swing and AWT, not JavaFX

Comment: I tried it by myself, and it is 100% working. Maybe your case is something different. Read the reference link shared.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Shreyas Dave didn't work for me anymore. Though I don't know why, here is what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // to avoid
    // [JRSAppKitAWT markAppIsDaemon]: Process manager already initialized: can't fully enable headless mode.
    System.setProperty("javafx.macosx.embedded", "true");
    java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    // end
    launch(args);
}
```

This was also pointed out here: [JavaFX screencapture headless exception on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320915/javafx-screencapture-headless-exception-on-osx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the JavaFX application you could also try to use TestFX run the application in a headless mode, to control it and to make screenshots.  To run your TestFX application in headless mode you have to start it with the following JVM parameters (to enable [Monocle](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Monocle)):

```
-Dtestfx.robot=glass -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dmonocle.platform=Headless -Dprism.order=sw
```

Moreover you might need to install Monocle first.  See [Headless testing with JavaFx and TestFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403410/headless-testing-with-javafx-and-testfx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that can be used interactively (displaying JavaFx dialogs) but also must be able to run non-interactive on a server without display.
Even though no GUI element is used in non-interactive mode, we got

```
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
```

This happens as soon as a class derived from `javafx.application.Application` is instantiated, which you normally do with your main class.

Here is the way I solved the problem:

- I created an additional class `GuiAppExecution`:

  ```
  import java.util.List;

  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  /**
   * JavaFx launch class for {@link AppExecution}.
   */
  public class GuiAppExecution extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
      List<String> parameters = getParameters().getRaw();
      AppExecution appExecution = new AppExecution();
      appExecution.launch(parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Launches the {@link AppExecution} as JavaFx {@link Application}.
     *
     * @param parameters program parameters
     */
    public void launchGui(String[] parameters) {
      launch(parameters);
    }
  }
  ```
- In the main class `AppExecution` I created a method
  `public void launch(List<String> parameters) {`
  which parses the parameters and launches the application for both interactive and non-interactive execution.
- The `main` method looks like this:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] parameters) {
    List<String> parameterList = Arrays.asList(parameters);
    if (parameterList.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.equalsIgnoreCase(BATCH_PARAMETER))) {
      AppExecution appExecution = new AppExecution();
      appExecution.launch(parameterList);
    }
    else {
      GuiAppExecution guiAppExecution = new GuiAppExecution();
      guiAppExecution.launchGui(parameters);
    }
  }
  ```

  with

  ```
  private static final String BATCH_PARAMETER = "-batch";
  ```

  as the program option that request the non-interactive execution.

Since `GuiAppExecution` (which is derived from `javafx.application.Application`) is not instantiated for non-interactive execution, the JavaFx environment is not started.