# Cannot run JavaFX in headless environment

Tags: unit-testing, javafx-8, testfx

In my test package, I have both regular unit tests and testfx test. When I try to run the entire test package, those testfx tests all failed and give the following exception:

org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: Cannot run JavaFX in headless environment

Does anyone one knows how to run testfx tests alone with other unit tests?

Comment: Quoting the TestFX-project: "Headless testing using Monocle", do you have a correct setup for this? Maybe duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27403410/1961102